# Images imported from ImagePicker being stretched

Tags: swiftui

I've encountered what I think is a bug, and I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this, and/or has a work around for it.

I have images imported from the device's camera via the UIImagePickerController representable. Having imported this image, I then save it to the documents directory, and then display it using the following code:

```
Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .frame(height: 300)
            .scaledToFill()
```

This shouldn't cause the image to distort, as scaled to fill should simply enlarge the image until it fits the frame without distorting it. However, i'm getting a fair amount of horizontal stretching in the final image:

[image: stretched image]

Has anyone encountered this problem? I don't think i'm missing anything obvious, as when I use it for images not taken with the camera then the code performs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the modifiers as below,

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "08-512")!)
  .resizable()
  .scaledToFill()
  .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
  //.clipped()
 }
```